# Why am I getting this Index out of range error?

Tags: python

I am a beginner at Python, and I was writing some code that would pick a random letter from a list, print it, then delete it from the list so it would not be picked again. The cycle repeats through a while loop.

```
import random

list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h" , "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

yn = "y"

while yn == "y":
 npat = random.randint(0, 25)
 print(list[npat])
 del list[npat]
 yn = input("Again?: ")
```

It works fine but sometimes, the random number which is picked is shown to be outside the index range.

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It should work fine in my opinion but there's a problem. Can anyone point it out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, don't call a list `list`. Give it another name.

The problem is after each time you get a letter, you delete that letter. So if the list is `[1,2,3]` and I get `3`, `3` is deleted.

When that happens, the list now only has 2 items. Earlier, `list[2]` would work. Now that `3` is gone, `list[2]` does not exist.

Either you have to remove the delete function or you have to setup a variable that decreases each time a letter is selected and get the random with that:

```
import random

lista = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h" , "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

yn = "y"
max = 25

while yn == "y":
 npat = random.randint(0, max)
 print(npat)
 print(lista[npat])
 del lista[npat]
 max = max - 1
 yn = input("Again?: ")
```

Comment: `max` is a Callable too, you know. :)

Comment: Thanks, I feel so dumb now. I told you I'm new. Your method makes sense to use, and I can't believe I didn't spot my mistake. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! If this was useful, pls mark this as correct!

Comment: @HashimBinTalha Don't feel dumb. You've asked a very good question. Don't underestimate the skill that takes. Not many first timers know how to write an excellent question like this!

Answer (score 7):

Every time you `del list[npat]`, the list gets shorter. Eventually `random.randint(0, 25)` gives you an index that's out of bounds.

Unrelated: `list` is a bad variable name, as you are masking the `list` builtin.

Answer (score 3):

The size of `lista` is changing, specifically its length decreases by 1 each iteration. This is why you get an `IndexError`.

Use `random.shuffle` before the loop and take letters from the end of the `list`, then you don't need to worry about the index. It's much simpler and makes the intent clear: print a random letter, without replacement, until all letters are exhausted.

```py
import random

letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h" , "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
random.shuffle(letters)

yn = "y"

while yn == "y" and letters:
    print(letters.pop())
    yn = input("Again?: ")
```

Comment: Best answer. :) I took a few minutes longer writing the same. Maybe because I wrote `letters = list(ascii_letters[:26]))` after importing ascii_letters from string :)

Comment: Good call. I prefer the name `letters` over `lista`. Constructing the `list` from `string.ascii_letters` is much better than explicitly constructing it from the lowercase alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you delete an element list size is decreasing. So while generating a random number between (0,25) there is chance of generating a number which is greater than the size of the list.
So instead of fixing the size to (0,25) change it to (0,len(lista)-1). It will work fine.